# Why does this runs twice?

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement, while-loop, background-process, system-tray

I made a program which runs using the [SysTrayIcon](http://www.brunningonline.net/simon/blog/archives/SysTrayIcon.py.html)

And even thou it works just fine, every time it checks something, it does it twice. I can fix it by reducing the chance by half, but that's a shortcut not a proper fix.

```
from systray import SysTrayIcon
from random import randint


def shutprogram(SysTrayIcon):
    something = getsomething()
    while True:
        if getsomething() != something :
            something = getsomething()
            if randint(0,100) <= 10:
                print "STOP, HAMMER TIME!"
                stopthis()
            else:
                print "You may pass"

menu = (('Start', icon.next(), shutprogram),)

SysTrayIcon(icon.next(),"Shut Program",menu)
```

Comment: Every time you say `getsomething()`, the `getsomething` function is called. Maybe you want to use a temp variable to avoid this.

Comment: But the getsomething(), is some other function which shouldn't interfere in the if-statment.

Comment: You are *calling* it in the if statement (`if getsomething() != something:`). And then if the result is true, you call it again: `something = getsomething()`.

Comment: I guess I phrase it wrongly. I'm not worried by calling the getsomething() twice, since it only gives me a str/int/whatever, what I don't want is the while loop running twice and checking 'if randint(0,100) <= 10'

In the prompt everytime it loops, I get: "You may pass" twice, or "STOP, HAMMER TIME!" twice, or a combination of both, where it should be only once.

Comment: Well.. the whole thing is in a `while True:`, so it's going to loop forever, right?

Comment: Yes it should, but when 'something' haven't change it wouldn't do it anything. It does that. But when 'something' changes it run's the 'if randint(0,100) <= 10:' twice, it rolls it twice, and check it twice, which sometimes get me a True False/False True, that's the problem.

Comment: Just an idea: are you double-clicking the icon? Maybe you only need to single-click.

Comment: It's a menu item, can't click it twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I got. When I tried to 'getsomething', it had to wait a bit because it had some delay which prompted was returning a string like 'wait, getting info'.